# W3C validation error "duplicate ID" although the ID is hidden

Tags: html, hidden, w3c-validation

In my website I use CSS3 media queries for different styles on mobile. Then in my HTML code I add some `div` to show only in mobile device that duplicate another `div` that I hide.

In W3C validation it is an error, with "Duplicate ID".

But the ID not is duplicate because one of this is hidden.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: For validity it doesn't matter, if the element is visible or not. It's enough for it to be on the page.

Comment: ok thanks! I will change the ID

Answer (score 2):

The [`id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-id-attribute)‘s value

> […] must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree […]

So it doesn’t matter if the element is visually hidden.

Make them unique, or use some other hook, e.g. a `class` value.